# xPath remove <br> and push a multi-line text into one array

Tags: php, xpath

I've been lurking Stackoverflow for a possible answer for hours and although I found some solutions, none worked in my case.

I need to get the text of the div and run it thru a `foreach` loop to eventually create a new database record for each div content.

Everything works until I face divs with multi-line content and `<br>` tags.

I have tried:

```
$quotes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, normalize-space('$quote'))]//text()");
```

But it doesn't seem like `normalize-space()` has any effect because instead of pushing the whole text into one array it creates a new array after every `<br>` instead.

More code:

```
$quotes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, normalize-space('$quote'))]//text()");
$authors = $finder->query("//*[starts-with(@class,'$author')]/child::a");

    foreach ($quotes as $key => $quote) {
        {
            $quote = trim($quote->textContent);
            $dataArr[] = $quote;
            $authorName = preg_split("/[\s,-,@]+/", $authors[$key]->textContent);

            if (count($authorName) < 5) {
                $authorName = $authorName[1];
            } else if (count($authorName) > 5) {
                $authorName = $authorName[1] . ' ' . $authorName[2] . ' ' . $authorName[3];
            } else if (count($authorName) > 6) {
                $authorName = $authorName[1] . ' ' . $authorName[2] . ' ' . $authorName[3] . ' ' . $authorName[4];
            } else {
                $authorName = $authorName[1] . ' ' . $authorName[2];
            }
            array_push($dataArr, $authorName);
    }
```

HTML structure that is extracted correctly:

```
<div class="b-list-quote2__item "><a href="/" class="b-list-quote2__item-text js-quote-text">
    A random quote here...
</a><div class="b-list-quote2__item-category">
    <a href="/quotes/albert-einshtein?q=17856">Albert Einstein</a>
```

In this case, I get an Array with the Quote and Author that I later chunk by 2 and use in other functions

`[0] => A random quote here...
 [1] => Albert Einstein`

HTML structure I'm having the problem with:

```
<div class="b-list-quote2__item "><a href="/" class="b-list-quote2__item-text js-quote-text" style="position: relative; max-height: none;">
    Quote line 0,
    <br>Quote line 1,
    <br>Quote line 2,
    <br>Quote line 3,
</a><div class="b-list-quote2__item-category">
    <a href="/quotes/karmelita-kruglaia?q=249176">Tesla</a>
```

In this case, a new array item is added for every line of text thus something like

`[0] => Quote line 0
 [1] => Quote line 1
 [2] => Quote line 2
 [3] => Quote line 3`

With no "author" in the array which in this case should be "Tesla".

How a good array should look:

`[0] => Quote line 0 Quote line 1 Quote line 2 Quote line 3
 [1] => Tesla`

Comment: Can you give some sample HTML source so we can test this?

Comment: @NigelRen Edited the post.

Comment: Sorry - what would you have in $quote and $author when you use those pages.

Comment: Edited again, hope this time I explained it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your xpath query is running, the last part is asking for each of the text nodes to be extracted separately (the `//text()` bit on the end of the expression).  Instead you just want the text of the whole element.  With DOM, each piece of text is a separate node, so

```
Quote line 0,
<br>Quote line 1,
```

Is two separate text nodes.  Your query is retrieving this (as you've found) as 2 elements.

So using

```
$quotes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, normalize-space('$quote'))]");
```

Should give you all of the text. The text will have line breaks in it, so you can do ...

```
$dataArr[] = str_replace("\n", " ", $quote);
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.